# "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" when code is added through the Code Snippet tool when editing

Tags: bug, edits, jsfiddle

This is a minor bug as it's purely visual and doesn't prevent site functionality, however I figured I'd report it anyway. The "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" warning box pops up when converting code within a post from plain code into a Code Snippet if a JSFiddle link also exists in the post. This warning appears when clicking the *Insert Into Post* button within the Code Snippet UI.

[image: Example]

As mentioned above, this is purely visual. Hitting the *Save Edits* button on the edit view applies the edits as it should.

Comment: Whenever I had this problem, a few clicks around the boxes would make the error go away.

Comment: I also experienced that issue if the OP didn't post code but links to jsfiddle without http:// at the start so that they aren't links, and you can't make them links cause of this error

Comment: @msrd0 that's because JSFiddle links without code present in the question aren't allowed. Usually when I come across a question like this I comment out the JSFiddle link (using HTML comments `<!-- -->`) and leaving the comment explaining what I've done and asking the user to add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know what causes the issue, but I don't know if its good to let OP post code where he has only broken links to jsfiddle