# Codepen link and Snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When asking a question, you can't just use a snippet and link to JSFiddle or Codepen, as for some reason it doesn't detect the snippet as valid code.

There was a question that had a link to codepen, also had a bunch of code properly indented, and I edited it as the text of the question wasn't that good. I also snippeted the code, and then I couldn't submit the edit as now it wasn't detecting any code indented or in backticks.

Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342339/why-does-snippet-not-count-as-code and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274664/links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-when-code-is-added-through-t

Comment: @Rene thanks - I always seem to use the wrong search terms when on meta annoyingly... any tips?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not 100% sure from those answers what the solution is. I can't even make-up if it is by-design. Do you mind linking to an example so I can have go at it to see if I can work out what is needed?

Comment: @rene this was the question in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142323/cant-align-image-with-div

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, that is by design.

When sloppy users leave a bare link to CodePen the quality filter kicks in.

So anything that looks like this:

> `https://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/MbarmG?editors=1100`

will not get past the check.

It is simply resolved by adding some markdown to that link:

> `[Codepen](https://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/MbarmG?editors=1100)`

so it no longer is a bare link.

Problem solved.

I've edited [Can't align image with div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142323/cant-align-image-with-div) with the above trick.

---

<sup>Please note that both JSFiddle and Codepen have license models that might disallow anyone else but the OP from bringing code one-on-one over from those sites.</sup>

Comment: Nicely done! :)

Comment: I don't know much about this "webby" stuff, but why do you need a CodePen link if you have a Stack Snippet? They seem redundant, with the Stack Snippet being preferable since it keeps all the content *here*, as part of the question.

Comment: @CodyGray well, CodePen (and JsFiddle) are a bit richer in functionality so there might be cases where it is simply easier to go the CodePen or JsFiddle instead of only relying on the StackSnippet. So, yes: do bring code from CodePen and JsFiddle in the question, preferable as a Stack Snippet but don't get rid of the link as that would make things harder for visitors, not easier.

Comment: Be careful when copying code from external sites to Stack Overflow; you may be changing the license of the code, something only the copyright owner should be doing...